# Promise is fullfilled but can not log the data from it

Tags: javascript, express

[image]

Client code:

```js
async function getCurrentState(){
  let response = await fetch(url);
  console.log(response.body);
  console.log(response.json());
}
    
getCurrentState();
```

Chrome shows that the promise is fulfilled and i can see from network tab that the json came through.. but I can't for some reason log the result out.

Comment: Like there is nothing output in the console at all? what about `console.log(response);` ?

Comment: The Promise is logged as soon as you make the call, before it's resolved. But the console has a live reference to the Promise, so when you expand it you see the updated state

Comment: I can see the promise in console, but my console.log() calls are not showing up there.

Comment: Do you see the response in the Network tab of DevTools?

Comment: Yes I can see the call to backend in Network tab and in the Preview tab I can see the json.

Comment: Response.json() returns another Promise, not the data directly. You need to await/then that too

Comment: @TobiasK. Works, thank you. You can post answer and I'll accept it if you want.

Comment: Your code shows two console logs. Your screenshot, [which should not be a screenshot](/help/how-to-ask), shows one thing. So: which console log are you showing us? And can you please turn that into a normal code block instead of an image?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`response.json()` returns another Promise, not the data directly, in fetch.

You need to await/then that too:

```
    let response = await fetch(url);
    let responsedata = await response.json();
    console.log(responsedata)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
async function getCurrentState(){
  let response = await fetch(url);
  console.log(response.body);
  console.log(response.json()); //response.json() is another promise that needs to be resolved
}
```

You need to resolve the promise that is returned by **response.json()**.

Try:

```
async function getCurrentState(){
  let response = await fetch(url);
  console.log(response.body);
  const data = await response.json();  //await resolves the promise and returns data
  console.log(data);
}
```

Useful link: https://javascript.info/fetch